# Google OAuth with Embedded Browser

Tags: google-oauth, wifi, google-identity, captiveportal

My captive portal allows my guest wifi to use their Google auth credentials in order to allow access to my wifi.

The portal triggers an OAuth 2.0 with Google service and get back the user profile.

Google decided to stop supporting OAuth 2.0 in Embedded browser on April 22nd 2017.

https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

As far as I know, there is no way to force IOS or Android devices to start a real browser during the captive portal detection process.

I have sent emails to both oauth-help@google.com and oauth-feedback@google.com. It's been a month and no response.

I get the feeling that these mailboxes are not monitored.

Did anyone get any alternative method?